# Elasticsearch index is 'snapshot' after reindex finish

Tags: java, elasticsearch, reindex

I'm using Elasticsearch 5.5.1 and Jest API for connecting.
I do "Reindex" from source index to new index using reindex action with waitForCompletion = false.
which retrieve task id.
I check the task id, when completed I tried to swap alias - delete the source index and give it's name as alias to the new index.
However I get error:
Cannot delete indices that are being snapshotted: [[my_source_index/_adsOlaQxy018Nl3FTMmQ]]. Try again after snapshot finishes or cancel the currently running snapshot."}

I'm wonder, why the source index is still snapshot when the reindex task is completed? and I can also see all the documents exist in the new index.
any idea what the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snapshotting process is completely unaware that an index is being reindexed. If you snapshot lifecycle policy is set up to run at regular intervals, you need to wait until the snapshotting is done before deleting the source index.

In other words, don't trigger the reindex process if you know it will somehow run at the same time as your snapshot process... or better make your reindex process smarter and detect if a snapshotting process is in progress, and if yes, wait until it's done before deleting the source index.

Comment: is there any way to check if snapshot in process using Jest Api?

Comment: Which version of ES are you running?

Comment: Elastic search 5.5.2

Comment: Yes, you can probably query the status of snapshots [with this](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/blob/master/jest-common/src/main/java/io/searchbox/snapshot/SnapshotStatus.java)